# Add looping functionality to clickable jQuery slider (2)

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

I have adapted a jquery slider program that was posted in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560017/add-looping-functionality-to-clickable-jquery-slider),

Please check out my JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2aycogod/

HTML code:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="news-item item-1">News item 1</div>
    <div class="news-item item-2">News item 2</div>
    <div class="news-item item-3">News item 3</div>
    <div class="news-item item-4">News item 4</div>
</div>
<button id="prev-item">Previous</button><button id="next-item">Next</button>
```

CSS:

```
.slider
    {
        position: relative;
        clear: both;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.slider .news-item
    {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
    }

.slider .item-1
    {
        left: 0;
    }

.slider .item-2
    {
        left: 500px;
    }

.slider .item-3
    {
        left: 1000px;
    }

.slider .item-4
    {
        left: 1500px;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
$( '#prev-item' ).click( function( event ) 
        {
            var animPrev = "+=500";
            if($( ".news-item" ).position().left=="0")
            {animPrev = "-=1500";}
            $( ".news-item" ).animate({
            left: animPrev,
        }, 1000, function() {
    });
});

$( '#next-item' ).click( function( event ) 
        {
            var animPos = "-=500";
            if($( ".news-item" ).position().left == "-1500")  
            {
                animPos = "+=1500";
            }
            $( ".news-item" ).animate({
                left: animPos,
            }, 1000, function() {
        });
    });
```

Now it's possible to loop slides from end to begin, but after several clicks in Next or Prevoius button, then slide effect doesn't work any more.

Could someone give me hand with this code?

Comment: Not sure if is appropriate to ask here to answer in another question. You should either edit post or add comments to the original [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560017/add-looping-functionality-to-clickable-jquery-slider)

Answer (score 2):

You should somehow prevent click queue, cause the consistency of your variable `animPrev` depends on it. So, before **preview** and **next** click check if is animated with this JQuery selector:

```
if( $(".news-item").is(':animated') ) {
    return;
}
```

Check here this selector: http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Fixed [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/3v57t69L/)